# ScrollView stops working after scroll+tap

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a custom Scrollview, HorizontalScrollview, and inside is a dynamic table. Each row in table has multiple TextViews with onclicklisteners.

The problem occurs if I swipe in Y direction, then tap on the screen once. Vertical Scrolling(ScrollView) will stop working, but horizontal Scrolling still works. Please enlighten me.

ScrollView:

```
public class ParentScrollView extends ScrollView {
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public ParentScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new YScrollDetector());
    setFadingEdgeLength(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

// Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction  
class YScrollDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if(Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

TableRowView and textview:

```
public void addRow(String[] data, int[] rowId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        TextView tv = parseTextView(data[i]);
        tv.setId(rowId[i]);
        tv.setFocusable(false);//try solving with this, no luck.
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ChooseTableActivity.class == (v.getContext().getClass())){
                    ((ChooseTableActivity) v.getContext())
                            .onClickRowCell(v);
                    //passes view to activiy class that does nothing yet.
                }
            }
        });
        this.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem in your onInterceptTouchEvent. If it rerurns false, all other events ( move, cancel and up ) will not be triggered for you. Try to replace
super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)
with
super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) || mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)

Comment: Didn't believe the solution was that simple.